# Install error in Windows 10 for IIS 10

Tags: iis, installation, windows-10

Error installing application compatible with iis = > 4 when I have iis -10 ( Windows 10)

As I can fix if I do not have the sources to generate the installer again with that dependency ?

thanks all for help!

[image]

Comment: Crappy software will think that 0 < 4, and they never know that IIS can go to 10. Find the vendor to see if they still exist and have an update, or dump the software and find an alternative.

Comment: You could try changing tje IIS version number in the registry, prior to the installation.
Look for "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\InetStp\" and change "MajorVersion" 10 to 7 for instance (source: https://www.saotn.org/install-iis-url-rewrite-module-windows-server-2016-iis-10/)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I change this in regedit but fail again. thanks again.